# 2 different dates from the same formula =TODAY()

Tags: excel, vba, date

I am entering a date into a cell (B2) using VBA
     Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = "TODAY()"

This brings up the date in US format e.g 03/04/2015 (4th March 2015)

If I enter the formula =TODAY() directly into the cell (not using VBA) it shows the date in UK formatt e.g. 04/03/2015 (4th March 2015).

Can anyone help me with the reason for this please and how to keep it in UK formatt no matter what the users locale setting is.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the format of the cell in VBA while you are setting its content.

```
With Cells(emptyRow, 2)
    .Value = "=TODAY()"
    .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
End With
```

This will at least keep the format you'd like for the cells being set from VBA.